# Single-column figure makes other column blank

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, multicol

I am editing a two-column paper (IEEE Conference Template) and there are some single-column figures to put into it.  The code is listed below:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\vspace{-0.1in}
\includegraphics[width=3.3in]{Figures/intervals_top1.png}
\vspace{-0.1in}
\caption{
(a) Fractions of SP intervals by size for the best site.
(b) The contributions of each size SP interval to duty 
factor.  Results for a range of stranded power models. The percentage below 
each is the duty factor.}
\vspace{-0.08in}
\label{fig:intervals_top1}
\end{figure}
```

However, putting this figure in one column will leave the other column on the right blank (see below).  If I remove this figure, there will be no blank any more.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. It seems that your figure is to wide for one column, however, without minimal working example is difficult say any particular about your problem. Try to delete `\vspace{...}` and set the figure width to `\linewidth`: `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}`. A possible reason for your problem is, that you have in second column float element with option `H` or some other no floating element, which can not be fitted into available space.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of figure width - with the IEEEtran template oversized figures will simply overrun the text in the second column, not leave any empty space.
That said, I was unable to reproduce the problem with the code snipped from above - @roymaztang please do provide a minimum working example.

Comment: About image width probably you are right, but the second possible cause I mentioned can not be confirmed nor rejected without MWE, which exhibit OP problem.

Answer (score 6):

I was also having the same problem when using IEEEtran.cls. In the template they have provided, `\usepackage{stfloats}` was mentioned. When I commented this, this problem was solved. I hope this will solve your issue as well.

Comment: I am not an expert in LaTeX. I was recently making a journal and that is when I encountered this problem. Both of the packages `fixltx2e` and `stfloats` caused the same issue. So I just commented both of them.

Comment: [`fixltx2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) is obsolete and hasn't made any difference to an *up to date* LaTeX installation for a little while (everything from [`fixltx2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) has now been implemented directly into the LaTeX kernel), it would be slightly surprising if that were causing the issue.

Comment: @PhilipJacob You know how to save a man's life. Coz you just saved mine. Thank you brother........

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a journal template and the solution turned out to be quite mundane.  Having a float at the beginning of a subsection forced the column next to it to become blank.  Putting the float after a paragraph of text fixed the problem for me.